# How to export query result into the csv in windows machine MySQL 8.0?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to export my query result to location
`C:\Users\useName\Desktop\locate`
using query

```
select*from  table into outfile 'C:\\Users\\userName\\Desktop\\locate\\ans.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

It is generating error

```
'   Error Code: 1. Can't create/write to file 'C:\Users\userName\Desktop\locate\ans.csv' (OS errno 17 - File exists)    0.000 sec
```

Although when I am trying to export using MySQL 8.0 workbench  manually using GUI button I can export it but I want to do this using query!
And I want to save it into particular location only !!

edit 1:

```
Error Code: 1. Can't create/write to file 'C:\Users\userName\Desktop\testR\ans1.csv' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)  0.000 sec
```

Comment: If the output file exists then you must either delete old file (MySQL cannot - do separately) or change output filename (for example, add creation datetime to the filename, use prepared statement).

Comment: It did not help

Comment: *OS errno 13 - Permission denied* - adjust filesystem access rights for the account which is used for MySQL service running.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Look at MySQL service properties for an account used for its running (network service by default). Then look for access rights for this account in the destination folder, add createfile/write privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to resolve the following error:

```
1)Press Windows+R
2)Type services.msc and hit enter
3)Search for MySQL service.
4)Right click on the service.
5)Go to properties.
6)Then go to Log On
7)set log on as local system account
8) restart the service.
```

Bam!! you are good to go wherever you have permissions you can write into file.

For new people like me Here are the steps to restart service:

```
  1)Press Windows+R
    2)Type services.msc and hit enter
    3)Search for MySQL service.
    4)Select it then on left side you see option to restart ,hit it!!
```